# Unable to connect to Docker .net Core 31. SDK container from host

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, dockerfile

I'm trying to access a .net core webapi hosted in a docker container from the browser on the host (Win 10 Pro 1903; Docker Desktop 2.1.0.5 using Linux containers).

Nothing special about the webapi; just a brand new `dotnet new webapi` project using the .net core 3.1 sdk.

I am able to access the webapi through docker interactive terminal and through kitematic, so everything is glitter there. Things start going astray when I try to connect to the container from the host. Access the container from the browser/ping fails (used localhost, 127.0.0.1, and container ip).

I've made sure everything is updated, reconfigured ports a few times, and have even tried things on a mac with the same results.

Here is the docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "webapi.dll"]
```

I'm not sure if its an issue with the SDK image (should I be using the nano image instead) or if its an issue with Kestral configuration (which I doubt).

Any suggestions would be awesome

**EDIT**
Docker-Compose

```
services:

  app:
    image: fooey/webapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:5001"
```

And for a manual launch
`docker run -p 8000:5001 --name api webapi`

Comment: You mapped the port when doing `docker run` or `docker-compose`, right?  Can you show how you're starting the container on your local machine?

Comment: @Matthew just updated with answers

Comment: This issue related to your SDN network created by docker so which network is used by your container to connect with each other and host   1 ) host , 2) bridge  3) overlay

Answer (score 1):

So, the issue turned out to be a couple of things.

1. The runtime image I was using is wrong, it shouldn't have been the SDK
2. The runtime (and SDK) both override launchSettings.json to use port 80 [shout out to Wael Kdouh and Kendall Roden](https://medium.com/@waelkdouh/developing-a-dockerized-asp-net-core-application-using-visual-studio-code-6ccfc59d6f6)

The appropriate way to handle this is with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:5000
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "webapi.dll"]
```